# Forcing the legend in Vega chart to draw (and then using it for data filtering)

Tags: legend, interactive, vega, stacked-chart

I have created [a stacked bar chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJIu2x9mbWwBm2s4oZ1pIAO41Z9NAHYADO5nwaZLGgAWTxkcJFlZGnEyNAEZJAZMNggaAC84NFBMAE8cdPQzWxlFBVS8zGs4GSgJTCRIiDQQUPDI6IBfGTVMABs8zLgAD0xGgDFrOm0IiHKaJgT1OwhmLt7GgGU4VUQmOAMAJnc9gEZtAFptcTZ7ReW6XpGatezV9DokbpooOyskBDyQMiKNgMHB2JDiWBsRSNabGOzmMwQODDVBHdwdEDJMjid4NVAAbVAOL+jTUfwY4kKIGI7wYeXxICycH0dgQNRgIAAujImJFZBkQMT-mS4NoKRM7JEcAkYXBelBhjI2Kp1Hj8QymSyZGzxC5uRrmdCZPY4HAANZcqQGrUgHUuGSyJCYdL6uRILKWhkwYGKBqc7kgbpIHbdNW29ndD3G01myN2R00OMO92mCwm812b0MAzmbT0UWOj2ctodIm-f5MYpIM1MKPU2n-KHyX21TAMBo8vkCoUw2pQM26fQQXRZbSS8TSlGYuVwBXwlUSMNN3awtsdkDVCnlOtWGyYHsOmjTZRzRLQgNBkNLxTN7Sr9t2Te6xQ78YmA9yI8zU9QrklqRliS6DVKGUDvHAH4go6zqNAA5CB0DgbB2gANS6FWNYeqWgrlqSdzpDIUFOv8sFjHu2jEGw3QMH8d59macCyCO2jIWhlbMphIBtAG0EoASgH-LuVLZt0jRYLg+BELQ0zUHQjBzEiijVLqEGYJQ1QIAQSApAIRxHHsWkCHArgBEgUB7FATAAGwBAEcB7AAnO4UBwAIriyAAHFATkOUcrhIGEBCKEg9gEHAVmOgIwYCAEAgeQ58gAMyObZVl7McsgOQ55lmE5exMLIBXmXAiUEEJalQBAxDfFCyAopkOT-JV1UhEOfRyHKNCkMU-LoNBBEgMuPWNP1XH-gJI2dd1NAKIsPouY05V2OU4IQGYtVoISIDZLki2Js6RogIMODQn1To0ZQ8gfN1jHaAAhAAvBcDDdKJ2E7cKNDkpSiogAUcq9R1127IxdjipgeKgFiOKiegIrg1xMjQ+8pK8uIAD6V1dSD-JxGG4PuGDP1HH+AHbY1jRIGQgJ8DBMiAsCOC1ptIAE9IUO+DDjTsdWzPcUqeAs0+wwBv93SyGq4gvd0AZIGG5XC6TDW7egwhsJEVM0xQdMAkCILMwSrM-YTAbKmGSwIJaf0zeL8tvorst23uwu5Io8M-Ur5Mq5i9F2Az+seobbMBmIbsCmLvUc9iKPoDznH-tbAOLfbwK6mCTt0MLhMyArqeYCTxaF0jYG9GqE3oAMiGrJ0FOx+CuMgMFUT-I4zgcq1LRRGg7iUO4sSN6nvXlHSDpsMgkQCsjsPbV9cAbAAjnSEJwAAFJgaOY1NOOUODUh5hvWM3bIlCwm7e-r5Em-Az1J+JDgACUY1kz26BZFXA0fY0HziIadhN2Q-wfB+F+rIMedQNCgF4pNa+M11wR2Ts7POJMMRpCBGgYelRBSfDKBUbCL8NxUXfkNe865P7oCbBrUSo9x4aAZPYOoagu5IxgCoHArR4xHlCJgWAoMHSzm-rwjc4IXKvVBgGf+9JG6CKYNRAaNMILxn0GaQE7pFGKDNMNYsz9cLAUISXWcecXzLVroNG8lD4xgInqgSBTo+JA2xsoWaOcbaA2FkYjEEjJ48KAkI50ZAoRZAOF8caOEfEIX0eVD8ZDTERC5tQ8BAooF9S3o4uBLiEF0B7B48EACvHcCasRfxL4glP3LgQ0C4EpjfgSL+Gu3sKFxLkJYiBbpajQIcbA746S+pfhPDU6E2Tm55MQAUvxASSklllgMWa-FTEzTTrHNg2Ax6LH0Y0Suayc61SdAAFRMSKGqig6qT05jHGefwACqP01i5CgDQf6ig14HxSYxHeP0IB72AFmX0qAWIAFIAASsE2iPwxJeOUAB5bqQZQToFCMobIiNQBQnmVOXoZhfrv0aG-TZM9+wAGE85uE6PhE50dp4rHSJMmQvQAHiAlptUAIEaLiDxHsGQEFqjyAFOC0MApIgHTMmoUg6CKiERwKNaxg1Qh3MRbM500xGh3V6FEegK9eIr1gofXYsDYL33vtoAAPoa7QfJbGau1ak2Ce9YIfWtZMc6CBKAfUfjIGksi0BHGwu6uk3dKB7AENxEsGJokQCyAgJgVEumvUaOE8CkTcIkp6P8MiEwAByuF+a2iUWXL2-xihzhzkCS2Uqkn2OmrNDEnK2DcqlURGCUqBhePAusrFzik7oDZhiVuLgpVYorm2kAeh6WeoxIHKGazX6DvgfkFOW5CZjr2M2l4jJp3dL+nO3UyCBZmToOO+sHrUQYmPGwBiAB1JwvbQA+ryOiZxMa+2TqjlzXRFSVWZvbeLMlL6h0YT5iGtgVE1CwufWc4A7s6C-JFA8I5Tp1WOreXQLweZZ5XLoDc2c9yZqPIvhjS1rzwYQH1XvYhrZ2y-OghdUj50PmGCDBAfADq2xOoTX8PebisgUYQxxveVS+lni48xy6vTZj9PY3nQTF1c5bnPks94kmWObtwLsCDmA2hPwwGwbqk9yinvaje7mQZ+yIx9kCc9l6ORSoM0endsr93WZ7q4QNwbixAA) where the dimension for the color of the stacked bars is selected from a drop down. (Can be **Country**, **Fruit Name**, etc.)

In the legend box I want to show colors assigned to fruit names. This shows fine when bars are stacked by fruit name

```
Fruit Name
* apple
* lemon
* ...
```

but otherwise is `undefined`

```
Fruit Name
* undefined
```

How can I force the legend to draw always?

Why do I want to do that? I would like to make the legend interactive, so that you can use it for filtering of the data shown in the graph. That way I could select - say - apple and plum in the legend but stack the bars by country or the order status. (Nice for data exploration.)

Comment: Interactive legend example:
https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/interactive-legend/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data source for the domain of the color scale needs to be changed from `deliveries` to `fruit`.

```
    {
      "name": "colscalefruitname",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "deliveries", "field": "fruitname"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category20c"}
    },
```

Here is an [updated chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAETJIu2x9mbWwBm2s4oZ1pIAO41Z9NAHYADO5nwaZLGgAWTxkcJFlZGnEyNAEZJAZMNggaAC84NFBMAE8cdPQzWxlFBVS8zGs4GSgJTCRIiDQQUPDI6IBfGTVMABs8zLgAD0xGgDFrOm0IiHKaJgT1OwhmLt7GgGU4VUQmOAMAJnc9gEZtAFptcTZ7ReW6XpGatezV9DokbpooOyskBDyQMiKNgMHB2JDiWBsRSNabGOzmMwQODDVBHdwdEDJMjid4NVAAbVAOL+jTUfwY4kKIGI7wYeXxICycH0dgQNRgIAAujImJFZBkQMT-mS4NoKRM7JEcAkYXBelBhjI2Kp1Hj8QymSyZGzxC5uRrmdCZPY4HAANZcqQGrUgHUuGSyJCYdL6uRILKWhkwYGKBqc7kgbpIHbdNW29ndD3G01myN2R00OMO92mCwm812b0MAzmbT0UWOj2ctodIm-f5MYpIM1MKPU2n-KHyX21TAMBo8vkCoUw2pQM26fQQXRZbSS8TSlGYuVwBXwlUSMNN3awtsdkDVCnlOtWGyYHsOmjTZRzRLQgNBkNLxTN7Sr9t2Te6xQ78YmA9yI8zU9QrklqRliS6DVKGUDvHAH4go6zqNAA5CB0DgbB2gANS6FWNYeqWgrlqSdzpDIUFOv8sFjHu2jEGw3QMH8d59macCyCO2jIWhlbMphIBtAG0EoASgH-LuVLZt0jRYLg+BELQ0zUHQjBzEiijVLqEGYJQ1QIAQSApAIRxHHsWkCHArgBEgUB7FATAAGwBAEcB7AAnO4UBwAIriyAAHFATkOUcrhIGEBCKEg9gEHAVmOgIwYCAEAgeQ58gAMyObZVl7McsgOQ55lmE5exMLIBXmXAiUEEJalQBAxDfFCyAopkOT-JV1UhEOfRyHKNCkMU-LoNBBEgMuPWNP1XH-gJI2dd1NAKIsPouY05V2OU4IQGYtVoISIDZLki2Js6RogIMODQn1To0ZQ8gfN1jHaAAhAAvBcDDdKJ2E7cKNDkpSiogAUcq9R1127IxdjipgeKgFiOKiegIrg1xMjQ+8pK8uIAD6V1dSD-JxGG4PuGDP1HH+AHbY1jRIGQgJ8DBMiAsCOC1ptIAE9IUO+DDjTsdWzPcUqeAs0+wwBv93SyGq4gvd0AZIGG5XC6TDW7egwhsJEVM0xQdMAkCILMwSrM-YTAbKmGSwIJaf0zeL8tvorst23uwu5Io8M-Ur5Mq5i9F2Az+seobbMBmIbsCmLvUc9iKPoDznH-tbAOLfbwK6mCTt0MLhMyArqeYCTxaF0jYG9GqE3oAMiGrJ0FOx+CuMgMFUT-I4zgcq1LRRGg7iUO4sSN6nvXlHSDpsMgkQCsjsPbV9cAbAAjnSEJwAAFJgaOY1NOOUODUh5hvWM3bIlCwm7e-r5Em-Az1J+JDgACUY1kz26BZFXA0fY0HziIadhN2Q-wfB+F+rIMedQNCgF4pNa+M11wR2Ts7POJMMRpCBGgYelRBSfDKBUbCL8NxUXfkNe865P7oCbBrUSo9x4aAZPYOoagu5IxgCoHArR4xHlCJgWAoMHSzm-rwjc4IXKvVBgGf+9JG6CKYNRAaNMILxn0GaQE7pFGKDNMNYsz9cLAUISXWcecXzLVroNG8lD4xgInqgSBTo+JA2xsoWaOcbaA2FkYjEEjJ48KAkI50ZAoRZAOF8caOEfEIX0eVD8ZDTERC5tQ8BAooH5DfN8FxCC6A9g8eCABXjuBNWIv4l8QSn7lwIaBcCUxvwJF-DXb2FC4lyEsRAt0tRoEONgakpOfUvwnmqdCLJzdcmIHyX4gJxSSyywGLNfipiZpp1jmwbAY9Fj6MaJXVZOdapOgAComJFDVRQdVJ6cxjjPP4ABVH6axchQBoP9RQa8D5bxvuDCAe9gBZl9KgFiABSAAErBNoj8MSXjlAAeW6kGUE6BQjKGyIjUAUI5lTl6GYX679Ghvw2TPfsABhPObhOj4WOdHaeKx0gTJkL0AB4gJabVACBGi4g8R7BkBBao8gBSgtDAKSIB0zJqFIOgiohEcCjWsYNUItz4UzOdNMRod1ehRHoCvXiK9YKH12LA2C9977aAAD76u0HyWx6rNWOIgLBPesEPpWsmOdBAlAPqPxkDSWRaAjjYTdXSbulA9gCG4iWDE0SIBZAQEwKiqTXqNHCeBSJuEiU9H+GRCYAA5XC-NbRKLLl7f4xQ5w5yBJbCVST7HTVmhidlbBOUSqIjBCVAwvHgTWRi5xXSjZ0EJhiVuLgJUYorq2kAehaUeoxIHKGqzX6DvgckxBW4u0yECU2l4jJp1pNnZnJBiNJVmToOO+s7rUQYmPGwBiAB1JwvbQDeryOiZx0a+2TqjlzXR5SlUZrbeLElL6h0YT5sGtgVE1DQufac4A7s6DfJFA8Q5TpVUOp3sbc+s9Ll0GubOO5M0HkXwxuaxiiG6AQF1XvYhrZ2zfOghdUj503mGCDBAfA9q2yOvjX8PebisgUYQxxvelTelni48xy6PTZh9PY3nQTF1c5bnPos94kmWMpy3K7CDmA2hPwwGwbqk9yinvaje7mQZ+zbpPeey9HIJUGaPQLXdMrr0Nl9a4ANQbixAA).